# make a wrapper function around map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a parameter into my `map` function in react. But after I wrap it around in another function, the return value becomes null (at least when I debug with `console.log(marker(NATURAL_EVENT_WILDFIRE) == null)`).

```
const markers = eventData.map((ev, index) => {
        if(ev.categories[0].id === NATURAL_EVENT_WILDFIRE) {
            return <LocationMarker key={index} lat={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[1]} lng={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[0]} onClick={() => setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title })} />
        }
        return null
    })
```

I want to turn the above function into something like below, where I can specify the id as a variable.

```
function marker(idx) {eventData.map((ev, index) => {
        if(ev.categories[0].id === idx) {
            console.log(ev);
            return <LocationMarker key = {index} lat={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[1]} lng={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[0]} onClick={() => {
                setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title });
                //support for toggle away info box
                setInfoBox(!infoBox);
            }} />
        }
        return null
    })}
```

The element is deployed as:

```
{markers} //no problem
{marker(NATURAL_EVENT_WILDFIRE)} //doesn't render
```

You can view the codebase [here](https://github.com/bradtraversy/wildfire-tracker/blob/master/src/components/Map.js)

Comment: you miss "return" before eventData.map

Comment: @quirimmo how come if the `return` is inside a `if` clause, that `return` would serve as a return for the outer scope(function) as well? Since I already have a return in the `map` why I can't just get it outside the `map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a return statement to your map function.

```
function marker(idx) {
return eventData.map((ev, index) => { //add return statement
        if(ev.categories[0].id === idx) {
            console.log(ev);
            return <LocationMarker key = {index} lat={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[1]} lng={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[0]} onClick={() => {
                setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title });
                //support for toggle away info box
                setInfoBox(!infoBox);
            }} />
        }
        return null
    })}
```

Answer (score 1):

You omitted to add `return` statement in `marker` function

You should add `marker` to the function or convert `marker` function to arrow one.

General function

```js
function marker(idx) {
    return eventData.map((ev, index) => {
        if(ev.categories[0].id === idx) {
            console.log(ev);
            return <LocationMarker key = {index} lat={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[1]} lng={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[0]} onClick={() => {
                setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title });
                //support for toggle away info box
                setInfoBox(!infoBox);
            }} />
        }
        return null
    })
}
```

Arrow function

```js
const marker = (idx) => eventData.map((ev, index) => {
    if(ev.categories[0].id === idx) {
        console.log(ev);
        return <LocationMarker key = {index} lat={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[1]} lng={ev.geometries[0].coordinates[0]} onClick={() => {
            setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title });
            //support for toggle away info box
            setInfoBox(!infoBox);
        }} />
    }
    return null
});
```